# svelte dev server only applies global styling after I save css file

Tags: svelte, rollup, rollupjs, svelte-3

I have a global.css file under public and I reference it  in index.html.

in App.svelte I put this code:

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="nav-center">
    <h1 class="nav-title">Budget calculator</h1>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="nav-btn">
    <i class="far fa-plus-square" />
    add item
  </button>

</nav>
```

and what I get is this un-styled page:

[image]

But if I open global.css and save (without making any change) I get the styled page:

[image]

So everytime I save App.svelte I loose the styling and when saving global.css they are back, any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Does the issue persist after restarting the dev server? Sometimes svelte/sapper behave better after a restart for some reason

Comment: Yes, it persist after restart, and I'm not using sapper

Comment: Is the code available on git for us to try for ourselves?

Comment: just download their official starter template and try it

Comment: I can't reproduce it with the default template. When you save `global.css`, livereload reloads & injects only this CSS file with a cache busting query param, so it does seem like a caching issue. If "Disable cache" in network dev tools panel doesn't work for you, check if you don't have a Service Worker, for example left by a Sapper app, ("Application > Service Workers" in Chrome) that bypasses your request to `global.css`. Try to check "Bypass for network" to make sure.